# Why do Brackets "][" need double escape "\\" to prevent interpretation by the shell?

Tags: command-line, bash, awk

Im using 'bash' shell and executing below 'awk' command on a file with records of file separated with number of different chars like Brackets, Colons, Parentheses as below sample record

```
...(field#13[field#14:]]:filed#18[filed#19)[...
```

However when I'm escaping "][" with single escape '\', awk command failing and I must double escape '\\' Brackets only to get my expected result, how does it needs to use double escape Brackets (in 'csh' shell it's same)?

```
awk -F"[\\[\\]:)(]" '{print $18}' inFile
filed#18
```

also please note this, that I know for all I can escape them with double escape '\\' like below, I just want to know why for Brackets this is mandatory?

```
awk -F"[\\[\\]\\:\\)\\(]" '{print $18}' inFile
filed#18
```

even using signle escape gives warning (except for Brackets), but still command execeute and result coming, thanks

```
awk -F '[\\[\\]\:\)\(]' '{print $18}' inFile
awk: warning: escape sequence `\:' treated as plain `:'
awk: warning: escape sequence `\)' treated as plain `)'
awk: warning: escape sequence `\(' treated as plain `('
filed#18
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple levels of quoting/escaping going on here. First, you have your `FS` regex (`-F "[\\[\\]\:\)\(]"`) in double quotes. That's what's giving the warnings:

```
$ awk -F"[\\[\\]:)(]" '{print $2}' file 
awk: warning: escape sequence `\[' treated as plain `['
awk: warning: escape sequence `\]' treated as plain `]'
awk: fatal: :, [., or [=: /[[]:)(]/
```

While single quotes just work:

```
$ awk -F'[\\[\\]:)(]' '{print $2}' file 
field#13
```

That's because anything in double quotes is first expanded by the shell. So, the shell first expands `\\[` to `\[` and then passes it to awk. You can see this happening with `set -x`:

```
$ set -x
$ awk -F"[\\[\\]:)(]" '{print $2}' file 
+ awk '-F[\[\]:)(]' '{print $2}' file
```

As you can see above, the shell ate the first escape. So don't use `"` here at all.

The next issue is that awk itself interprets the escapes twice. Because the `-F` can accept special escapes like `\t` and `\r` etc, it will first try to read `\[` as a single, escaped character. Since `\[` is the same as `[` (unlike, say `\n` which is not the same as `n` since `\n` is a newline), it gives you a warning message, explaining that it treated `\[` as `[`.

So, you need the first escape to escape the `\` itself, and the second escape to escape the `[`. In other words, in `\\[`, the 1st `\` is escaping the second `\` so that what `awk` finally receives is `\[`.

It might be easier to understand if you consider something like this:

```
$ echo -e 'a\tb'
a   b                  ## prints a tab character
$ echo -e 'a\\tb'
a\tb                   ## prints a literal \t
$ echo -e "a\\tb"      
a   b                  ## prints a tab because of the double quotes
$ echo -e "a\\\tb"     
a\tb                   ## 3ple escaping! Prints a literal `\t` again.
```

The last example above is the most telling. Since the string to be echoed is in double quotes, it is expanded by the shell first (that eats one `\`), then by `echo -e` (that eats another `\`) and is finally printed as a literal `\t`.